# Error when using moveit alongside gazebo

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When trying to execute a successfully planned path in gazebo the execution fails and the following warning appears:

```
[ WARN] [1503953317.867847912, 22.680000000]: Failed to validate trajectory: couldn't receive full current joint state within 1s
```

I am using rviz moveIt plug-in

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/269803/error-when-using-moveit-alongside-gazebo/) by [MohammedHyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/30707/mohammedhyder/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-08-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the (lack of) information given, I can't say for sure. But, from the warning that you posted there's a timeout issue.Your model may not be publishing the joint states on the correct topic. From @gvdhoorn's comment on [this answer](https://answers.ros.org/question/252114/failed-to-validate-trajectory-couldnt-receive-full-current-joint-state-within-1s-error/?answer=252620#post-id-252620), you can try making

> sure that `joint_state_publisher` gathers the `JointStates` published on `/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states` and republishes them on `/joint_states`.

with

```
<node name="joint_state_publisher" pkg="joint_state_publisher" type="joint_state_publisher">
    <param name="/use_gui" value="false"/>
    <rosparam param="/source_list">[/move_group/fake_controller_joint_states]</rosparam>
</node>
```

You can always use a [Google search of ROS Answers and the error](https://www.google.com/search?q=Failed+to+validate+trajectory%3A+couldn%27t+receive+full+current+joint+state+within+1s+site%3Aanswers.ros.org) which will give many results.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MohammedHyder](https://answers.ros.org/users/30707/mohammedhyder/) on 2017-09-15**:
Thanks jayess ,it works properly after adding this node tag to the launch file. Thank you very much!!!.
Sorry for coming late but i have seen your answer few minutes ago.